# Android secure JSON response

Tags: android, json, http-post, android-volley

I'm developing an application that performs a POST request and gets a JSON response from the server (JSON). The problem is, in the server-side, I don't want another app consuming the response, only my app (think like your facebook account, you perform some queries againts the server and it returns a json to your facebook app, so you can see the results). The difference is, there is no need for a user to create an account to use the app, anyone can use it.
What is the best way to protect the response from the server ?

I'm using php on the server-side (along with mysql) and the response is being returned as a 
`echo json_encode($response)`

Hope you guys understand and thanks in advance !

Comment: are u thinking about something as simple as passing a key from your app to the service, and then only returning json if the key is correct?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. What you mean, something like oAuth ?

Comment: Client side can encrypt it with key and send to server. Server will use the key to decrypt and use the same key to encrypt response. Only client knows how to decrypt it.

Comment: Seems like a nice approach, what is the best way to do this on android ? I mean, which libs (api's ?) should I use ? Any tutorial or enlightening would be great !

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to help your app identify itself to the server:

1. Use SSL for all of your communication to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack.
2. Have a secret key that identifies your app, and when communicating with the server, hash it, you can add salt a timestamp. On the server side remove the salt, decrypt it, check the timestamp to protect against repetition attack, and check the app identifier.
3. You can have the server send a challenge, and the client side must hash that challenge with a timestamp using a secret hash function in order to resume communication.

There are many more ways to protect your server, these are just a few.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply ! Using SSL is ok, but how can accomplish items 2 and 3 on android ? I mean, which libs or api's should I use ? I'd like to know if there is some nice tutorial or something like this to get me started ! Thank you very much !

Comment: You can choose which networking infrastructure to use (personally I use Google Volley but there are many options), then you have to create custom methods to parse HTTP requests / responses that you send / receive. I'm not aware of specific tutorials, but I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: I have some custom requests developed, if you need any help just create a new topic and let me know !

Answer (score 0):

A user account approach is kinda what you may need. You can embed a key with the requests that validates against a approved-key table where the key is stored. Quick and dirty, but a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry not to mention, but my app works like google maps, querying over location A from B, so an user account would be pointless for a good user experience ! That's why your approach wouldn't be so good in my case. Anyway, thanks for the reply !